# Slowly rising RAM consumption in Kubuntu 18.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ram

I have installed Kubuntu 18.10 with backports and upgraded to Plasma 5.14 latest version. I have observed gradual increase in RAM usage from idle state (Booted the system and opened System Monitor). I see no change in RAM usage increase from user owned processes. I can't figure out which process is taking up RAM. How do I figure it as this is becoming problematic when using laptop for long duration?

PS: I can post more info which might be needed. I don't know which specific details will help.

Update:
Check the RAM usage here. I can't understand what is causing this much RAM usage.
[image]

Update 2:
Here are the additional output files required. Uptime - 5:53 hours. System was left idle all along.
[image]

```
top - 19:26:13 up  5:53,  3 users,  load average: 0.54, 0.18, 0.06
Tasks: 204 total,   1 running, 203 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.6 us,  4.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 89.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.5 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7899.4 total,   3623.2 free,   2970.1 used,   1306.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  13898.0 total,  13898.0 free,      0.0 used.   4517.5 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3255 anoop     20   0 1107192 229964 156400 S   0.0   2.8   0:08.01 kded5
 3309 anoop     20   0 1287336 217944 108984 S   0.0   2.7   1:40.62 plasmashell
 3301 anoop     20   0 3076980 131328  85076 S   6.2   1.6   2:55.66 kwin_x11
 3381 anoop     20   0 1024428 127404  77380 S   0.0   1.6   0:07.72 latte-dock
 2481 mysql     20   0  840888  79284  16936 S   0.0   1.0   0:17.00 mysqld
 3812 anoop     20   0  542748  70820  58428 S  12.5   0.9   5:24.72 ksysguard
 1819 root      20   0  495276  70252  49320 S   6.2   0.9   1:21.96 Xorg
 3307 anoop     20   0  567548  69472  54248 S   0.0   0.9   0:00.45 krunner
 3834 anoop     20   0  480840  62728  52376 S   0.0   0.8   0:02.52 konsole
 3356 anoop     20   0  459788  51824  44744 S   0.0   0.6   0:03.91 kdeconnectd
 3298 anoop     20   0  430052  44656  39384 S   0.0   0.6   0:00.34 ksmserver
 3552 root      20   0  378056  43452  12772 S   0.0   0.5   0:04.67 packagekitd
  289 root      19  -1  111760  43344  42460 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.56 systemd-journal
 3317 anoop     20   0  494968  39756  35332 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.13 polkit-kde-auth
 1513 mpd       20   0  503764  38216  31760 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.27 mpd
 3098 anoop     20   0  337324  37948  33740 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.15 kwalletd5
 3262 anoop     20   0  349452  37812  33480 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.10 kaccess
 3376 anoop     20   0  464124  37788  33396 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.46 org_kde_powerde
 1492 root      20   0 1667516  37200  29516 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.65 libvirtd
 3501 anoop     20   0  334120  36928  32792 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.08 kuiserver5
 3268 anoop     20   0  332568  36784  31424 S   0.0   0.5   0:00.25 kglobalaccel5
 3252 anoop     20   0  332720  36368  32396 S   0.0   0.4   0:00.88 klauncher
 3291 anoop     20   0  519344  30652  27536 S   0.0   0.4   0:00.10 kactivitymanage
 1249 root      20   0  775924  27856  16936 S   0.0   0.3   0:03.60 snapd
 1810 postgres  20   0  269844  27596  25572 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.38 postgres
 2502 root      20   0  114880  21792  19056 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.15 smbd
 3346 anoop     20   0  278192  21504  19392 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.07 gmenudbusmenupr
 3322 anoop     20   0  276976  20304  18268 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.06 xembedsniproxy
 1494 root      20   0  126720  20152  12276 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.14 unattended-upgr
 3251 anoop     20   0  132368  18748  16412 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.04 kdeinit5
 3339 anoop     20   0  268540  18456  16392 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.08 kscreen_backend
 3383 anoop      9 -11  936116  17764  13680 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.18 pulseaudio
 1190 root      20   0   48632  17444   9432 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.16 networkd-dispat
 3911 root      20   0   43132  17344   9152 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.10 update-apt-xapi
 3899 anoop     20   0  132756  17316  14844 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.61 file.so
 3499 anoop     20   0  132716  17288  14888 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.00 file.so
 1213 root      20   0  462968  16588  13704 S   0.0   0.2   0:07.88 NetworkManager
 1613 root      20   0  151760  13784  12632 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.04 sddm
 1968 root      20   0   88884  12804  10760 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.69 nmbd
 3028 root      20   0  105148  12756  11712 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.08 sddm-helper
 3391 anoop     20   0   22888  12664   6100 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.21 python3
 1199 root      20   0  523764  12380   8976 S   0.0   0.2   0:02.59 udisksd
 1975 whoopsie  20   0  295424  12188  10664 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.06 whoopsie
 1438 root      20   0  224200  11188   9796 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.08 cups-browsed
 1439 root      20   0  258748  10280   6804 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.32 polkitd
 1883 postgres  20   0  269844  10132   8096 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.28 postgres
 1061 root      20   0  331936   9644   8248 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.05 ModemManager
 1195 root      20   0  141652   9504   8736 S   0.0   0.1   0:03.51 thermald
    1 root      20   0  195200   9420   6720 S   0.0   0.1   0:02.18 systemd
 2980 root      20   0  277276   8680   7652 S   0.0   0.1   0:01.49 upowerd
  858 systemd+  20   0   54660   8480   7152 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.19 systemd-resolve
 1196 root      20   0   50244   8080   6900 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.03 cupsd
 3033 anoop     20   0   46296   8012   6680 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.07 systemd
 1881 postgres  20   0  269952   7768   5712 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 postgres
 1210 root      20   0   21548   7628   6880 S   0.0   0.1   0:03.69 wpa_supplicant
 1069 root      20   0  254160   7472   5924 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.74 accounts-daemon
  313 root      20   0   28696   7092   3084 S   0.0   0.1   0:04.67 systemd-udevd
 1885 postgres  20   0  270244   7036   4808 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.21 postgres
 2774 root      20   0  114980   6940   4200 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.12 lpqd
 1887 postgres  20   0  270152   6888   4664 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.01 postgres
 3472 anoop     20   0   56300   6860   6208 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.01 obexd
 3288 anoop     20   0   54168   6760   6288 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 kwrapper5
 3434 anoop     20   0  316632   6488   5784 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 at-spi-bus-laun
 3617 root      20   0   11668   6244   4928 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 dhclient
 1882 postgres  20   0  269844   6180   4136 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.30 postgres
 1071 root      20   0  239044   6148   5284 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.03 iio-sensor-prox
 1789 root      20   0   11668   6112   4844 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.01 dhclient
 1068 root      20   0   38344   6096   5328 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.13 systemd-logind
  862 systemd+  20   0  113912   5756   5152 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.07 systemd-timesyn
 1202 message+  20   0   22936   5672   3752 S   0.0   0.1   0:04.76 dbus-daemon
 2586 root      20   0  111464   5632   3040 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.02 smbd-notifyd
 3279 anoop     20   0  161396   5036   4460 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 dconf-service
 3449 anoop     20   0  244344   5004   4564 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 agent
 1017 root      20   0   10300   4896   1772 S   0.0   0.1   0:01.76 haveged
 3838 anoop     20   0   12992   4892   3168 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.06 bash
 3182 anoop     20   0   21788   4716   3740 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.22 dbus-daemon
 1063 root      20   0   18296   4500   4104 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.02 bluetoothd
 1128 syslog    20   0  240572   4388   3392 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.13 rsyslogd
 1886 postgres  20   0  124768   4336   2320 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.25 postgres
 2587 root      20   0  111456   4292   1700 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.01 cleanupd
 3486 anoop     20   0   15092   3900   3588 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.13 libinput-debug-
 1127 avahi     20   0   18704   3712   3328 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.17 avahi-daemon
 2300 root      20   0   11760   3708   3204 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 mysqld_safe
 3447 anoop     20   0   21224   3636   3300 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon
 7969 anoop     20   0   25992   3592   3016 R   6.2   0.0   0:00.02 top
 1192 root      20   0   94244   3552   3228 S   0.0   0.0   0:02.98 irqbalance
 1194 root      20   0   17388   2980   2712 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.04 cron
 3044 anoop     20   0  214888   2884     36 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 (sd-pam)
 3394 rtkit     21   1  163036   2740   2488 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.27 rtkit-daemon
 3351 root      20   0   11164   2528   2020 S   0.0   0.0   0:01.52 mount.ntfs
 3359 root      20   0   11168   2424   1916 S   0.0   0.0   0:01.14 mount.ntfs
 3830 anoop     20   0    6664   2396   2136 S   0.0   0.0   2:23.99 ksysguardd
 3509 anoop     20   0    6660   2304   2036 S   0.0   0.0   1:11.08 ksysguardd
 3100 anoop     20   0    2560   1800   1688 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.05 startkde
  309 root      20   0   83324   1596   1420 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 lvmetad
 2482 root      20   0   18640   1208   1040 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 logger
 1188 root      20   0    2492    852    784 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 acpid
 2042 root      20   0    2448    752    688 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 none
 2037 kernoops  20   0   24476    424      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.48 kerneloops
 2030 kernoops  20   0   24476    420      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.50 kerneloops
 2616 libvirt+  20   0   27460    344      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.07 dnsmasq
 2617 root      20   0   27432    344      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 dnsmasq
 3216 anoop     20   0    5152    320      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 ssh-agent
 1406 avahi     20   0   18504    316      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 avahi-daemon
 3249 anoop     20   0    4400     84      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 start_kdeinit
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd
    8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 ksoftirqd/0
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:06.42 rcu_sched
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
   13 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 watchdog/0
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
   16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 watchdog/1
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 migration/1
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.11 ksoftirqd/1
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd
   21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2
   22 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.07 watchdog/2
   23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 migration/2
   24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 ksoftirqd/2
   26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd
   27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3
   28 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 watchdog/3
   29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
   30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 ksoftirqd/3
   32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kblockd
   33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns
   35 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_kthre
   36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kauditd
   38 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:01.11 kworker/0:2-cgroup_des+
   40 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 khungtaskd
   41 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 oom_reaper
   42 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 writeback
   43 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kcompactd0
   44 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
   45 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khugepaged
   46 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 crypto
   47 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
   48 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
   50 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
   51 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 md
   52 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 edac-poller
   53 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq
   54 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 watchdogd
   58 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0
   59 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u9:0-hci0
   60 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-kthrea
  105 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld
  106 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 acpi_thermal_pm
  112 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ipv6_addrconf
  121 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kstrp
  138 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 charger_manager
  189 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  190 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_0
  191 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  192 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_1
  193 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
  194 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_2
  195 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_3
  196 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_3
  201 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 kworker/2:1H-kblockd
  203 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.22 kworker/3:1H-kblockd
  205 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 kworker/0:1H-kblockd
  206 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kworker/1:1H-kblockd
  238 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 jbd2/sda7-8
  239 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ext4-rsv-conver
  316 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 loop0
  317 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 loop1
  347 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 irq/50-mei_me
  355 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cfg80211
  427 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:06.05 kworker/2:3-events
  447 root      -2   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 i915/signal:0
  448 root      -2   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 i915/signal:1
  449 root      -2   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 i915/signal:2
  450 root      -2   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 i915/signal:6
  451 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 nvkm-disp
  516 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u9:1-hci0
  524 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ttm_swap
  706 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 jbd2/sda8-8
  707 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ext4-rsv-conver
 2046 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 iprt-VBoxWQueue
 2054 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 iprt-VBoxTscThr
 3482 root      10 -10       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 krfcommd
 6665 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.56 kworker/3:1-events
 7237 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:02.56 kworker/1:0-events
 7537 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:2
 7618 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0-events
 7818 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 kworker/0:1-events
 7828 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.44 kworker/u8:2-phy0
 7915 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 kworker/u8:1-events_po+
 7928 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kworker/u8:0-events_po+
 7933 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0-mm_percpu_+
 7940 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.07 kworker/u8:3-phy0
 7944 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:1-events
 7952 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kworker/0:0-events
 7960 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:1-events
 7962 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:2-events
 7965 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:3-events
```

Update 3:
Output of `slabtop -s -o c`. Unable to add whole output due to character limitations of the post.
[image]

Comment: just use `top` or `htop` also you can install `glances`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was deleted by some senior users and hasn't been undeleted even after editing with updated information. hence this new answer :

I figured the cause in my case was a faulty RTL8732BE driver. here is how I resolved it :

Updated the Wifi Drivers from here :
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

More info on this issue and the humongous memory leak can be found here :
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/401

Also, in my case, after 2 weeks(or so) of stable use of Kubuntu 18.10, an apt upgrade post that bumped up the Kernel and the Linux Firmware. Soon after that I noticed this leak.

Check your kernel version and if it is 4.18.XX, and if you are using a laptop with this Wifi CHip/Driver combination, then that is what it must be for you too.

Comment: Thanks. That was spot on. It fixed the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to spot the highest memory users by using Kubuntu's *System Monitor*.

Click on the *Process Table* tab and then, in the dropdown on the right, choose whatever you wish. The image is for *Programs Only* but other choices are available.

[image: Kubuntu's System Monitor]

Or, whenever you want to record the highest memory users, you can run

```
top -bn1 -o %MEM | head -15
```

Change `-15` to whatever you like. You could use `>` or `>>` to redirect output to an appropriately named file.

```
dkb@kububb:~$ top -bn1 -o %MEM | head -15
top - 09:55:39 up  3:51,  3 users,  load average: 0.24, 0.73, 0.76
Tasks: 203 total,   1 running, 159 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  6.1 us,  2.9 sy,  0.1 ni, 89.2 id,  1.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8034932 total,  4434372 free,  1128288 used,  2472272 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8117244 total,  8117244 free,        0 used.  6432348 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
25120 dkb       20   0 1452488 218576 151404 S   0.0  2.7   0:02.37 kded5
25323 dkb       20   0 1496736 183752  17908 S   0.0  2.3   0:01.23 mysqld
25179 dkb       20   0 3842812 171040  90636 S   0.0  2.1   0:13.81 plasmashell
25528 dkb       20   0 1085940 161936 113640 S   5.9  2.0   0:28.35 chrome
25983 dkb       20   0 1131148 150864 104756 S   0.0  1.9   0:01.91 soffice.bin
27700 dkb       20   0  754940 133880  81112 S   0.0  1.7   0:19.92 chrome
25172 dkb       20   0 3289868 104440  66276 S   0.0  1.3   0:37.38 kwin_x11
25409 dkb       20   0 1338772  87336  70300 S   0.0  1.1   0:00.56 akonadi_mailfil
dkb@kububb:~$
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. KDE connect seems to be the culprit. I have booted my system and automatically KDE connect has paired my laptop with the phone. In this case I observed the gradual increase in RAM consumption. Again I performed a fresh boot and disabled all networking immediately. In this case there was no increase. I will try to check this in a fresh install of Kubuntu and file a bug if it is actually the case.

Comment: Very interesting! I use KDE Connect but only exactly when I want to transfer stuff to or from my cellphone. So I guess I did not notice the creep in RAM.

Comment: Update: I was wrong. KDE connect is not causing this increase. @DK Bose, can you look at the update and suggest what to do?

Comment: @Anoop, please run `top -bn1 -o %MEM > mem.txt` and post the entire output in your question. Interestingly, of the processes we have in common based on the ksysguard image, I seem to be using slightly more RAM except for kded5 and krunner! And I don't have mysqld running. And I don't use Tor. Have you installed any plasma widgets? Some of those can eat up RAM.

Comment: Sorry was a bit busy. Please check the update 2.

Answer (score 0):

smemstat is also a useful tool for tracking memory consumption, for example:

```
sudo apt install smemstat
```

and track the memory change every second in "Top" mode:

```
sudo smemstat -T
```

or track memory changes every 10 seconds:

```
sudo smemstat 10
```

Comment: The problem I have is no user process is taking up so much memory. Then which other processes can be using this much memory?

Comment: If no user process is using up memory then there are two possibilities, either free memory is being used by the kernel for caching data from the file system or it's a memory leak in the kernel. If it's just the file system cache then the kernel will ensure this memory is reclaimed when free memory gets low so there is no need to worry about this.  One can see where memory is being allocated using the command:  cat /proc/meminfo